# Views - create relationship on relationship?

Tags: 7, views

I'm confused with Views' query altering and adding joins. Need help (or at least a comprehensible documentation with code samples, because I've never found one).

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have 2 node types, Writers and Books. I use taxonomy to group Books by Writers. I've created a field in my taxonomy terms that references respective Writer articles. It looks like this:

- Books by Writers (dictionary)

  - Books by Isaac Asimov (taxonomy term, WriterId = 1 - references Isaac Asimov node)

    - I, Robot (Book node)
  - Books by Harry Harrison (taxonomy term, WriterId = 2 - references
    Harry Harrison node)

    - West of Eden (Book node)

Now I'm trying to build a view that looks like this:

- Isaac Asimov (Writer node title)

  - I, Robot (Book node title)
- Harry Harrison (Writer node title)

  - West of Eden (Book node title)

All in all, I need something like Book Nodes join Taxonomy Terms join Writer Nodes. In Views UI I'm able to display Book titles and add a relation to Taxonomy so that I can display all Taxonomy term fields. It looks like this:

- 1 (WriterId from taxonomy term)

  - I, Robot
- 2 (WriterId from taxonomy term)

  - West of Eden

How do I join Taxonomy and Writers to get access to Writer node titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you don't really need taxonomy here. Instead you can reference Book node to Writer node directly.
Of course, you can solve the problem without modifying your current structure. I will show how to create such View using [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) as referencing field. I recommend this module for creating references in Drupal 7 as it is powerful and stable.

1. First, create new View for Books content type:
   [image]
2. Add relationship to taxonomy term:
   [image]
3. Now you can add one more relationship to Writers nodes. Here [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) comes into play:
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now you can output all you want from Book node, from relative taxonomy term or from relative to that term Writer node. Just select appropriate relationship to use:
   [image]
   Here I added title from Writer node and excluded it from display.
   You may want to group output by writer and it can be done in Format settings:
   [image]

If you didn't use unnecessary dictionary, you would not need the second step.

About a year ago I started with NodeOne series [Taming the Beast: Learn Views with NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) and [Using the Reference modules](http://nodeone.se/en/using-the-reference-modules) by Johan Falk and I hope this information will help you too.

---

*Done with love to Isaac Asimov.*

Comment: Oh yessss. It workssss.